# Recursion with for loops does not return anything

Tags: python, recursion

I have this recursion function I wrote (Simplified, it is much longer but the idea stays the same)

```
def rec(point,length):
   if 1<length<=8:
        str_adj = '23456'
        for adj in str_adj:
            return rec(adj, length-1)
   elif length == 1:
       return 1
   else:
       return 0
rec('1',2)
```

[Disclaimer: I know the code looks weird and some parts are not needed because I simplified the function. ]
Now, when I run this code I get: **1**, however the output needs to be **5** as I iterate over each letter of the string '23456' (which has 5 letters) and for each letter I call it with length of 1 (as I decrease it 2-1=1)  and each time we get length=1 we return 1, so it should return 1 five times..
I've sat down to debug and break down the code into multiple parts and tried many many different version of it, such as removing 'return' in the loop, but when doing it, the output is None...
Can someone please help me to spot the mistake? thanks!
In python code, I am trying to do the following:

```
rec('2',1)+rec('3',1)+rec('4',1)+rec('5',1)+rec('6',1) = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 +1 = 5
```

as each time we call rec(?,1) = 1

Let's say the str_adj = '123456789' and length = 2
then I want to output to be:
  rec('1',1)+rec('2',1)+ etc.. until + rec('9',1)
each time we call rec(?,1) = 1 so it should return 9

Comment: show a few inputs and the expected outputs

Comment: @Thankyou I've added what I am expecting (last line of code right above the tags) tell me if I need to clarify more

Comment: Please help! :)

Comment: that's not a concrete example, you still are using `...` to represent missing code. define a concrete input and an expected output. it would be helpful if you provide more than one.

Comment: @Thankyou I've updated the post, I am trying to 'accumulate' these letters basically, but I get 1 as a return and not 5 times 1

Comment: It still make no sense, you function could be as easy as `def rec(_, n): return 1` and `rec('foo', 'bar') + rec('a', 'b') + rec('z', 0)` is equal to `1 + 1 + 1` is equal to `3`.

Comment: @Thankyou ok, i will simplify even more, sorry for being misunderstood, I need the recursion to output the length of str_adj but in a weird way, the length is 2 and each time we get length =1 we return 1 , so i want to iterate over str_adj letters and call each letter with length=1 so it will return 1 for each letter and so it will return the number of letters

Comment: to see why, you always call `rec(?,1)` where `length = 1` and your condition is `if 1 < length ...` which is always false. The next condition is `if length == 1`, which is always true, so the return is always `1`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the end goal is, but your logic is breaking the code. When you call rec the first time, it enters the first "if" statement, and from there calls

```
rec('2', 1)
```

This call of the function enters the "elif" statement, returns 1, and then ends.

If you could clarify what you are trying to accomplish I can try to help fix this logic.

Comment: Basically in this example where str_adj='23456' which has 5 letters, I try to call this recursion on each letter (as seen in the loop) and then it should return 5 as I am trying that everytime we get the recursion with length=1 then it will accumulate until we don't have anything to iterate on and so it should return 5 , or in python code:  
I am trying that the for loop will do this:
return rec('2',1)+rec('3',1)+ ... +rec('6',1) = 5

Comment: Another issue is that each time you call the function you redefine "str_adj", so on each iteration of recursion you will start over on '2'.

Comment: I know, it's just to simplify, note that it does not matter as in the second time we won't get into that if statment because length is 1 and it is not between 2 and 8

Comment: In the example you posted you would need to add a call of the "rec" function from the "elif" statement, otherwise it will only every return "1" one time.

Comment: I know that, but adding in the elif: return 1+rec(??,length-1)  won't do anything, it still does not work, I am trying to accumulate the results using the for loop which will call 5 times with length 1 and thus return the number 1 , 5 times and the result will be 5 .. but It does not accumulate and I dont know how to fix it!

Answer (score 1):

Your expected behavior does not match what is happening. You're never modifying `str_adj` and setting `str_adj` each time to equal `23456`. In your for loop, `adj` will always be `2` unless you change it. In order to do so, it will also have to not be a variable local to the function.

You will also need something to keep track of your iterations.

Doing your example like this, will give you the result you want. You could make it much better, but I did my best to change it and match your format.

```
def rec(point,length, str_adj, iterations):
  print("rec(", point, ", ", length, ", ", str_adj, ", ", iterations, ")")
  if 1<length<=8:
      for adj in str_adj:
        str_adj = str_adj[1:]
        iterations = iterations + 1
        return rec(adj, length-1, str_adj, iterations)
  elif length == 1:
      return iterations
  else:
      return 0

iterations = 1;
str_adj = '23456'
print(rec('1',4, str_adj, iterations))
```

Comment: Hi, I am not allowed to change str_adj and the length, the length is always 2, I know it sounds weird but that is because the problem is much bigger and I simplified things, basically I need the for loop to call for each letter of str_adj, the recursion with one less length. however just to get the point I am saying that length=2 all the time. so if str_adj = '123' and length =2 then I want the for loop to iterate over 1 2 and 3 and for each of them call rec with length one. because it does not matter what char is it, because length=1 returns 1 -> i want it to accumulate and return 1+1+1 = 3

Comment: @SendHelp If you can't modify `str_adj` then you'll still need a temp variable and set it to `tempVar = str_adj[1:]` When you call the function again, you have left the previous scope, and `str_adj` is again set to `23456` if you don't pass a modified version of it `adj` will again be 2 in the for loop. As others have said, you will always eventually hit your case `length == 1` and it will return 1. Hence why I created an `iteration` variable. It sounds like you're trying to solve a problem where recursion is not the answer, or you don't understand what happens with recursion.